# Can you identify the spigot attached to this water heater?

Tags: water-heater, metal, corrosion, spigot

I have a corrosion problem on my new indirect fired water heater. HTP technical support, the company that makes the heater, wants to know the alloy of the spigots attached to the hot water inlet and outlet pipes. I have appended below a photograph of one of the spigots. Do you know the make/model of this spigot or its alloy?

[image]

Note that it is definitely cast because it has a parting line.

Comment: Can you take a better picture please? More indirect lighting is needed

Comment: My guess would be nickel coated brass, but again, I would want a better picture.

Comment: That's a stainless steel tank, right?

Comment: @GregoryNickoloff Yes

Comment: There's something "funny" about those other fittings then. Brass and copper should be OK and are recommended in the installation documentation. (http://www.htproducts.com/literature/lp-32.pdf) I suspect that the other fittings (from the tank, the "T" and so forth) are not good. I think I'd replace the connections with fittings that you know the composition and quality of.

Answer (score 1):

It's called nickel brass, white brass or nickel-plated brass. It's perfectly acceptable. The bigger issue in the picture is the copper fitting attached to the tank, it should be a barstock or brass FIP. A bar stock or brass fitting or dielectric union should be put in between any black iron and copper fittings. The tee looks a little odd. But if it's brass it should be fine.

Not exactly the same I'm sure, but similar. 
[image]

http://www.jomarvalve.com/products/categories/boilerdrains/brass.html

Comment: You can always revise your deleted answer and reopen it rather than leaving an orphan, FYI. No big deal.